# Size of a Keras model increases after a new model is instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Title is self explanatory, the toy code is shown below:

```
from pympler import asizeof 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model_1 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

print('Model 1 size = ', asizeof.asizeof(model_1))

model_2 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

print('Model 1 size = ', asizeof.asizeof(model_1))
print('Model 2 size = ', asizeof.asizeof(model_2))
```

Pympler is a Python memory profiler. The output of the code is:

```
Model 1 size =  68624
Model 1 size =  92728
Model 2 size =  92728
```

The desired output is:

```
Model 1 size =  68624
Model 1 size =  68624
Model 2 size =  68624
```

> Python version: Python 3.6.8
>
> Keras version: 2.3.1
>
> Tensorflow version: 2.1.0

I suspect this is a bug and I will submit an issue in their Github if this is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asizeof.html
it says,

> If all is True and if no positional arguments are supplied. size all current gc objects, including module, global and stack frame objects.

Maybe what you're looking for is `basicsize`.

```
from pympler import asizeof 
import gc
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model_1 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

gc.collect()
print('Model 1 size = ', asizeof.basicsize(model_1))

gc.collect()
model_2 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

print('Model 1 size = ', asizeof.basicsize(model_1))

print('Model 2 size = ', asizeof.basicsize(model_2))
```

They should give the same size.